# In MonetDB, how can I get the date as an integer?

Tags: sql, date, integer, representation, monetdb

I want to be able to do something like

```
SELECT cast(my_date_col AS int) FROM my_table;
```

I would like to get the integer which MonetDB uses internally, i.e. the value you'd find if you looked into the BAT structure and got the appropriate element in code in MonetDB's GDK. Now, AFAICT, this internal value is the number of days since the Epoch, being Jan 1st on "Year 0" (so January 3rdt year 2 would be 366+365+2 = 732).

The best I could actually manage is

```
SELECT my_date_col AS int - cast('1-1-1' AS date) - 366 FROM my_table;
```

As MonetDB won't accept "Year zero" dates. This is rather an ugly hack, I'd like to do better. Help me?

Comment: I don't see anything in the [monetdb docs](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/Temporal) that suggests it supports an epoch data type. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': I'm not sure what you mean. Epoch (in this context) is the point in time from which you count time, or date, as an offset in usecs, or msecs, or days or whatnot. On traditional UNIX systems, the Epoch was Jan 1st 1970.

Comment: "Epoch" is essentially an integer. A date is essentially *not* an integer, and can't be cast to an integer in standard SQL. Are you just trying to get the number of days from 1970-01-01 to my_date_col?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': (Edited) Well, yes, sort of, but not 1970-01-01 but rather whatever MonetDB is using internally. Which I believe is Jan 1st, "year 0".

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the number of days between "my_date_col" and 1970-01-01, in standard SQL you'd just subtract the one from the other. Your platform, monetdb, seems to support this syntax, but I don't have it installed. I wrote these examples in PostgreSQL.

```
select current_date - date '1970-01-01' as num_days;
```

```
num_days
--
16213
```

Check that result by adding 16213 days to the current date (2014-05-23).

```
select cast ((date '1970-01-01' + interval '16213' day) as date) as target_date
```

```
target_date
--
2014-05-23
```

The cast is necessary, because the result of this addition is a timestamp, not a date.

In your case, you want a column name instead of "current_date".  So you're looking for something along these lines.

```
select my_date_col - date '1970-01-01' as num_days
from your-table-name;
```

Comment: @einpoklum: Maybe you should edit your question, and add those details. I looked at the source code, but I didn't see anything relevant. (That doesn't mean a lot.)

Comment: @einpoklum: I mean include enough details in your question so *we* can see what *you* see. (I didn't make that clear earlier.)